# value not updated when incrementing mutable ref

Tags: reference, ocaml

Below is an extract of code :
(the problem is visible by testing only this extract)

```ml
let cptIdCO = ref 0;; (* compteur : id Classe et Object globale *) 

let makeEtiClassOrObj =
  cptIdCO := !cptIdCO + 1;
  "ClObj_" ^ (string_of_int !cptIdCO) ^ ": NOP\n";;

let compileClass cls =
  print_string "-- compileClass\n";
  (*fillClass cls;*)
  print_string makeEtiClassOrObj;
  
and compileObject obj =
  print_string "\t-- compileObject \n";
  print_string makeEtiClassOrObj;
```

When calling `compileClass` or `compileObject` several times, the output is always `ClObj_1: NOP` so it seems that the reference is not updated and I don't understand why.

I saw some uses of `^:=` and `!^` but it don't work and I don't understand the difference between the normal and `^` versions.

Comment: One way to debug this kind of thing is to add an output print in the value you expect to do something. If you just put `print_int (!cptIdCO)` in `makeEtiClassOrObj` you would have immediately seen that it printed only once ;-)

Comment: Suggestion: `cptIdCO := !cptIdCO + 1; "ClObj_" ^ (string_of_int !cptIdCO) ^ ": NOP\n"` => `incr cptIdCO; Printf.sprintf "ClObj_%d: NOP\n" !cptIdCO`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the way you update the reference, but that `makeEtiClass` is not a function, just a variable holding a string, that happens to increment `cptIdCO` once before initializing it.

A function differs from a variable in that it takes arguments. You can use unit, `()`, if it doesn't need anything else.

This will do what you expect:

```ml
let cptIdCO = ref 0;; (* compteur : id Classe et Object globale *) 

let makeEtiClassOrObj () =
  cptIdCO := !cptIdCO + 1;
  "ClObj_" ^ (string_of_int !cptIdCO) ^ ": NOP\n";;

let compileClass cls =
  print_string "-- compileClass\n";
  (*fillClass cls;*)
  print_string (makeEtiClassOrObj ())
  
and compileObject obj =
  print_string "\t-- compileObject \n";
  print_string (makeEtiClassOrObj ())
```